# Examples of architecturally well-designed ASP.NET WebForms sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, mvp

What's an example of a reasonably modern, well-designed, fairly complex ASP.NET webforms site, with source code available? Particularly that use MVP or MVC patterns.

Note: I'm not looking for sites that use the ASP.NET MVC framework. I'm looking for sites built with traditional webforms, even if they happen to use the MVC pattern

Comment: Do you mean "well-designed" in terms of visual look & feel, user-interaction, or MVC/MVP architecture elegance?

Comment: Great question.  However, you should probably specify whether you want MVC OR Webforms.

Comment: well-designed architecture (good question - will edit title). and i'm not looking for ASP.NET MVC, i'm more interested in traditional webforms for this question. that said, webforms can use the MVP or MVC patterns, and I would probably expect any well-designed site to use one of those patterns for separation of concerns

Answer (score 3):

As for MVC, it's more of a tutorial, but [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) is a pretty good app/tutorial. MVC is quite new, so good well-architected, free sites aren't as common. I'd love to see a few. There's a PDF with NerdDinner that walks through the application.

For Webforms, [XD World Recipes](http://www.myasp-net.com/) is a well-architected n-tier application. It's a bit old ( 2 years ), which makes it nice for learning the basics of N-Tier, before we had all the syntactic sugar of Linq etc.

Comment: NerdDinner is pretty shitty app/tutorial. The tutorial is full of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Testable DNN Module](http://testdrivendnnmodule.codeplex.com/) - it is implemented using the [Web Forms MVP](http://webformsmvp.com/) framework.  For further information on web forms MVP, I would recommend listening to the following [Hanselminutes podcast](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=220).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ModelViewPresenter.aspx

This post is from a few years ago. It does a great job of showing a full-fledged, practical example of using an MVP pattern on ASP.NET Web Forms.

Billy McCafferty has examples of 3 different levels of complexity. I recommend taking a look at the "sample MVP enterprise solution".

Also, here's a great article by Jean-Paul Boodhoo on MVP with Web Forms:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx