# ASP .Net - Scalability and Complex Computation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I recently came across [this](http://mobile.baselinemag.com/c/a/Projects-Networks-and-Storage/Inside-MySpacecom/) article about how *Myspace* handled scalability issues and at one point adopted ASP .Net framework which resulted in improvements in the site's performance. Pardon my ignorance, this came as a surprise to me because I never knew about ASP .Net being used in such big websites which routinely face heavy traffic and handle huge computation.

My Questions are, Is ASP .Net a good framework to use for such websites? Which other popular sites use ASP .Net framework?

Comment: Consider that all of Microsoft's sites are build using ASP.NET or some other .NET technology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of architecturally well-designed ASP.NET WebForms sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650373/examples-of-architecturally-well-designed-asp-net-webforms-sites)

Answer (score 1):

This site was built in ASP.NET C#, for example. :)

The .NET framework is just as capable as any other framework. How well a site performs really depends on the developers putting it together.

I believe MySpace was first built with Cold Fusion, which is notoriously slow. I'm not surprised that they experienced performance gains after switching to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty.  A good example is this very site you're on.

Of course, it's also up to how you design your site.  No platform will make up for a bad design, but there's absolutely no reason why ASP.NET can't scale properly.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to that scale, it's mostly depending on infrastructure and a scaleable architecture. The major difference I think, and I say it from experience, if running in a windows environment, it often takes a "few" machines more than it would take if you we're running i.e. *nix. But hey, theres always Mono!

Quoted High Scalability:

> "Their system had " “hundreds of hacks to make it scale that no one wants to touch," which hamstrung their ability to really compete."

And:

> "Because of their infrastructure MySpace can’t change their technology to make new features work or make dramatically new experiences."

http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/25/did-the-microsoft-stack-kill-myspace.html